# Data type for currency values in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on database homework for school. I'm not able to think right now with lack of sleep I've been getting, but I know this is a simple question.

I have this create table statement and in it, I am supposed to have 3 columns `cusNo`, `add`, and `balance`, which I can do fine. But my problem lies in the last column. the last column is for balance and is supposed to have a numerical value of 5 digits. to do so, when I create the column for balance, would I just have to create it as a double?

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
  cusNo char(3),
  add varchar(20),
  balance double
)
```

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: @Andy do you mean DECIMAL? How would I store $32.75 as an INT? Multiply by 100, and have to divide every time I want to use the value?

Comment: @AndyLester wait. what???? office space, "give a penny, take a penny."?

Comment: @AndyLester If you use an integer how do you store decimals?

Comment: @AaronBertrand store the cents as a separate column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You round up, duh.

Comment: @AndyLester If only some database somewhere would invent some sort of currency-based data type! ;)

Comment: @AndyLester that makes no sense. So every time you read or update the data, you have to shift the decimal place? What does that gain you?

Comment: @AndyLester And what if I need to convert money from other countries?, should I ignore any currency that has less than one penny?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? postgres?

Comment: Looks like Microsoft Access. `sql` is *so* specific and helpful.

Comment: sorry, i am using microsoft access

Comment: @AndyLester, actually for money in databases, you usually want to use a floating point type which is perfectly convertable to base 10.  These go by names like DECIMAL, NUMERIC, or MONEY.  In PostgreSQL the implementation is base 1000.  Other implementations may vary.  One of the first lessons one learns writing accounting software is not to store money in ints either.

Comment: (It's confusing because most db's support both base 2 floating points and base 10 floating points and you want to make sure you use the base 10 types.  But as a simple example, in accounting I may want to accrue fractional cents in expenses across multiple transactions and I cannot do this with ints per se.)

Comment: @AndyLester, yes it does float.  3.7 * 10^32 is a floating point representation in base ten and this is not far from the way decimal types can be handled in dbs.  The problem with binary floating points is very specific, namely that the portion behind the point does not losslessly convert to base 10.  It has nothing to do with whether the point floats and everything to do with binary to decimal conversion.

Comment: For example in LedgerSMB we use arbitrary precision (decimal-safe) floating points all the way through our accounting software.  This does not lead to *any* of the traditional problems that floating point numbers do representing money.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `DOUBLE` in SQL Server.

And I would advocate for `DECIMAL` over `MONEY`. `MONEY` has [known accuracy issues](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal), [very rarely wins the performance race](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal), and is very inflexible in terms of what you can store. With `DECIMAL` you can choose scale and precision freely.

Comment: oh ok. I'm thinking of java, c++ with double. oops

Comment: @user2145290, don't use base 2 floats in your app code to represent money.  The best solution is to use an arbitrary precision floating point library instead.

Answer (score 3):

You normally don't use double/float for money (sorry, not just "normally", but you should never store it as non-precise type). Depends on RMDS you are using, you choose one or the other precise numeric type . `money` - SQL Server, `decimal`- MySQL, `NUMBER` - Oracle

**Update**
I forgot to mention that SQL Server also has `decimal` type which you may (and many people do) prefer over `money`.

Comment: I would push this one step further and say that you should use `DECIMAL(xx,xx)` in SQL Server. I've had problems with overflowing the `MONEY` type and tend to prefer `DECIMAL`.

Comment: when using DECIMAL, what do the numbers inside the parenthesis mean. does the first number mean that you can only have x amount of numbers and display x amount of places after the decimal point?

Comment: `decimal(14,2)` means total number of digits 14, and 2 after the decimal point. Number of digits to display is entirely up to client application.

Comment: @swasheck, I am not sure about that.  I would tend to use unrestricted decimal types to represent money any time there is any possibility of needing to accrue something like a cent over several transactions (VAT or sales tax is a very common case there).  There are very many cases where you want to do this and so good, base 10 floating point support is absolutely needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use Decimal for balance. Normally, up to two decimal works fine but you can change as per your need.
 So you should use:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
  cusNo char(3),
  address varchar(20),
  balance NUMERIC(7,2)
)
```

Comment: Edited answer. Actually, add is reserved keyword so use address instead or any other name.

Comment: yea, even after changing that, i still get the same message saying that there is a syntax error in field definintion and highlights the word decimal

Comment: would it matter if i am using access 2010 and using the query in sql view?

Comment: YES!! THAT WOULD MATTER FOREVER!! Always be as specific as you can about the problem you're facing, so that error messages and data types can be known and not just guessed at.

Comment: replace decimal(7,2) with number if you are using access 2010. Answer updated.

Comment: i tried replacing it with number and numeric, and still no success

Comment: but i am able to do something like this: `balance Number`

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (cusNo INT(3), add MONEY(5), balance MONEY(5))
```

Assuming you're trying to add totals to each other the MONEY data type is what you want here (and youre on sql server).

Comment: Like @swasheck, I disagree that MONEY is the right choice here (or ever).

Comment: For one ddl in a school project the student could learn the limitations, but yes I wouldn't use it in my career.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Access use the `Currency` data type for dollar amounts.  In SQL Server either use `DECIMAL` or `MONEY`.

Comment: add is a reserved word you need to use [add], or better yet use a different name.

Comment: i changed add to address and still ran into the same problems

Comment: I tested CREATE TABLE tablename2
(
  cusNo char(3),
 address varchar(20),
  balance Currency
) and it works fine in Access 2010.

Comment: yea, i just did that myself just now